# Accessing Video Duration via AJAX in YouTube API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, youtube-api

I have been trying to create a small script that accesses a YouTube video by its `id` and determines its duration.

Here is my script:

```js
var vidID = "";

var vidData;

var vidDuration;

function getResponse() {
  $.getJSON( "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=unSlPx7Zu-w&part=contentDetails&key=AIzaSyCSMBWe5CbW122szJGvGjQ6UrktPL4Z0Mw", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    
    vidDuration = data;
    
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    });
    
    $('body').append (JSON.stringify(data));
    
    $( "<ul/>", {
      "class": "my-new-list",
      html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );
  });
}

getResponse();

console.log(vidDuration.items[0][contentDetails][duration]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Console Results:

```
"error"
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
    at felepivuni.js:28:50
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.4.min.js:1:13924
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.4.min.js:1:10866"
```

As you can see, this works almost as intended with the output. It gives us the stringified JSON, then the 2 main JSON objects.

But after that, I just get
[Object object] twice..

Here is the structure of the packet we are receiving in response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XlbeM5oNbUofJuiuGi6IkumnZR8/ny1S4th-ku477VARrY_U4tIqcTw\"",
 "items": [
  {

   "id": "9bZkp7q19f0",
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XlbeM5oNbUofJuiuGi6IkumnZR8/HN8ILnw-DBXyCcTsc7JG0z51BGg\"",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT4M13S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "regionRestriction": {
     "blocked": [
      "DE"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Although I know this problem has arisen before, I believe my circumstances are sincere, and I still haven't found an answer to my problem.

Whenever you run the above code snippet, the console logs *undefined*, and the output, like stated above, has [Object object], which is expectable...

I know this is dragging out, but I'd really appreciate an explanation to why my code isn't working!

Even though I know this exists, [Youtube Video Duration API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101416/youtube-video-duration-api-v3), it doesn't help me solve my problem, so I am still asking this..

Thanks much!

- Noah

Comment: It appears that it is almost impossible to pass any of the JSON values outside of the handler function... I have been unsuccessful in many attempts to, but I have been able to get the console to log the duration from within the handler function... What is this?

Comment: Did you really post your API key???

Comment: Yes @StanStrum , Its only temporary, I can always get a new one :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling $getJson which is asynchronous.

getResponse(); //You need to wait for this function to return